# Reusing Linq to Entities' Expression<Func<T, TResult> in Select and Where calls

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, lambda

Suppose I have an entity object defined as

```
public partial class Article  
{  
    public Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }  
    public Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }  
    public UserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }  
}
```

Based on some properties of an Article, I need to determine if the article can be deleted by a given user. So I add a static method to do the checking. Something like:

```
public partial class Article  
{  
    public static Expression<Func<Article, bool>> CanBeDeletedBy(int userId)
    {  
        //Add logic to be reused here
        return a => a.UserId == userId;
    }  
}
```

So now I can do

```
using(MyEntities e = new MyEntities())  
{
    //get the current user id
    int currentUserId = 0;

    e.Articles.Where(Article.CanBeDeletedBy(currentUserid));  
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to reuse the logic in CanBeDeletedBy while doing a Select, something like:

```
using(MyEntities e = new MyEntities())  
{
    //get the current user id
    int currentUserId = 0;

    e.Articles.Select(a => new  
    {  
        Text = a.Text,  
        CanBeDeleted = ???  
    };  
}
```

But no matter what I try, I can't use the expression in the select method. I guess that If I can do

```
    e.Articles.Select(a => new  
    {  
        Text = a.Text,  
        CanBeDeleted = a => a.UserId == userId
    };
```

Then I should be able to use the same expression. Tried to compile the expression and call it by doing

```
    e.Articles.Select(a => new  
    {  
        Text = a.Text,  
        CanBeDeleted = Article.CanBeDeletedBy(currentUserId).Compile()(a)
    };
```

but it won't work either.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Or if it isn't possible, what are the alternatives to reuse business logic in both places?

Thanks

Pedro

Comment: Compiling the expression is the right choice and it compiles and works for me. If it were me, I would also factor out the compilation. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine, but throws a NotSupportedException exception: "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Tried to compile the expression outside of the Select into a Func<Article,bool> and use it inside, with the same result.

Comment: Btw, if I use a plain Func<Article, bool>, and use it in the Where method, then the query will be executed on the client, which is not the intended purpose.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad - missed the fact that you're using EF - it works fine with linq to objects :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-using expression trees is a black art; you can do it, but you would need to switch a lot of code to reflection and you'd lose all the static checking. In particular, working with the anonymous types becomes a nightmare (although `dynamic` in 4.0 might be workable).

Further, if you cheat and use `Expression.Invoke`, then it isn't supported by all providers (most noticeably not on EF in .NET 3.5SP1).

Unless this is a major pain point, I'd leave it with duplication. Or do you *need* to re-use the expression tree?

Comment: Don't really need to re-use the expression tree. It was just to try not duplicate security related code. But I will do it for now, and see if I can refactor the code later.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What I did is I used PredicateBuilder which is a class in LinqKit  and also AsExpandable() http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx to build up expressions and I stored them Statically as

```
public readonly Expression<Func<T,bool>>
```

in a static class. Each expression was building on a previous expression thus reducing the amount of duplication.

As the previous question by Marc Gravell suggests this kinda thing is a black art, but thankfully a lot of the work has been done by other poeple.